# How to create test cases for Javascript rest get call?

Tags: javascript

```
module.exports.get = function(req, url, callback, errorCallback) {
  https.get(getOptions(req, url), (response) => {
    handleResponse(response, callback, errorCallback);
  }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error('MYAPP-GET Request.', e);
    if (errorCallback) {
      errorCallback(e);
    }
  });
};


function handleResponse(response, callback, errorCallback) {
  let rawData = '';
  response.on('data', (chunk) => {
    rawData += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', () => {
    if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
      callback(checkJSONResponse(rawData));
    } else if (errorCallback) {
      errorCallback(rawData);
    }
  });

}

function checkJSONResponse(rawData) {
  if (typeof rawData === 'object') {
    return rawData;
  }

  let data = {};
  if (rawData.length > 0) {
    try {
      data = JSON.parse(rawData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Response is not JSON.');
      if (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      data = {};
    }
  }

  return data;
}
```

I am learning more about writing JUnit test cases for apps written in Javascript.

Below is what I have so far. I know it is not correct. Need help writing code to cover the above. If there are any good links to learn more about JUnit test cases please place them also in the reply. Thank You.

```
describe('>>> CRUD tests', () => {
  it('+++ test > get method', () => {
    
    const getSpy = jest.spyOn(crud, 'get');
    const httpAPISpy = jest.spyOn(http, 'get');
    getSpy.mockReturnValue(httpAPISpy.mockReturnValue());
    expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: NOTE: junit is for the *Java* programming language, not *Javascript*. Also, spyOn is for things you can't control (like `console`). You shouldn't need it for a function you wrote yourself. As for the rest this is a request for a tutorial on unit test writing, can you narrow the scope to a specific question about the code?

Comment: Agreed. Need good links to learn on java script testing? Can you point me to some of them, so that i can read and understand more. I know there are hundreds of links and sites, but looking for few good sources for java script testing.

Comment: We explicitly disallow questions about library/tool/tutorial recommendations, see item 3 in [this page from the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Test 1: Get a successful response from a valid URL
describe("get", () => {
  it("should get a successful response from a valid URL", async () => {
    const url = "https://www.google.com";
    const expectedStatusCode = 200;
    const expectedData = {
      name: "Google",
      domain: "www.google.com",
    };

    const response = await module.exports.get(null, url, (data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual(expectedData);
    });

    expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(expectedStatusCode);
  });
});

// Test 2: Get an error response from an invalid URL
describe("get", () => {
  it("should get an error response from an invalid URL", async () => {
    const url = "https://www.google.com/asdfasdf";
    const expectedStatusCode = 404;
    const expectedData = null;

    const response = await module.exports.get(null, url, (data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual(expectedData);
    });

    expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(expectedStatusCode);
  });
});

// Test 3: Get a JSON response
describe("get", () => {
  it("should get a JSON response", async () => {
    const url = "https://api.github.com/users/bard";
    const expectedStatusCode = 200;
    const expectedData = {
      login: "bard",
      name: "Bard",
      email: "bard@example.com",
    };

    const response = await module.exports.get(null, url, (data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual(expectedData);
    });

    expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(expectedStatusCode);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Import the module and the dependencies
const { get } = require('./your-module.js');
const https = require('https');

// Use a mock server to test the requests
const nock = require('nock');

// Define some test data
const testUrl = 'https://example.com/api';
const testReq = { headers: { 'User-Agent': 'test' } };
const testRes = { message: 'success' };
const testErr = { message: 'error' };

// Define a helper function to mock the https.get method
function mockGet(options, response) {
  nock('https://example.com')
    .get(options.path)
    .reply(response.statusCode, response.body);
}

// Define the test suite
describe('get', () => {
  // Test the happy path
  test('should call the callback with the parsed JSON response', (done) => {
    // Mock the https.get method with a 200 status code and a JSON body
    mockGet(getOptions(testReq, testUrl), { statusCode: 200, body: testRes });

    // Call the get function with the test parameters
    get(testReq, testUrl, (data) => {
      // Expect the data to be equal to the test response
      expect(data).toEqual(testRes);
      // End the test
      done();
    }, (error) => {
      // Fail the test if the error callback is called
      done(error);
    });
  });

  // Test the error path
  test('should call the error callback with the raw response', (done) => {
    // Mock the https.get method with a 400 status code and a non-JSON body
    mockGet(getOptions(testReq, testUrl), { statusCode: 400, body: 'Not Found' });

    // Call the get function with the test parameters
    get(testReq, testUrl, (data) => {
      // Fail the test if the callback is called
      done(new Error('Callback should not be called'));
    }, (error) => {
      // Expect the error to be equal to the test error
      expect(error).toBe('Not Found');
      // End the test
      done();
    });
  });

  // Test the exception path
  test('should call the error callback with the error object', (done) => {
    // Mock the https.get method with an error event
    mockGet(getOptions(testReq, testUrl), new Error('Network Error'));

    // Call the get function with the test parameters
    get(testReq, testUrl, (data) => {
      // Fail the test if the callback is called
      done(new Error('Callback should not be called'));
    }, (error) => {
      // Expect the error to have a message property
      expect(error).toHaveProperty('message');
      // End the test
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).